# Memory Allocation in C using mmap and memset

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, heap-memory, mmap

I need some help understanding why I'm getting a segmentation fault after I run my code, or why it doesn't stop when the memory used exceeds memory. I've been trying to do various things to see where the cp and ip are and most of the time they're the same. I've built this code off of what our professor gave us. Different version of the code that I wrote will give me "p6 should have been NULL, but is *address*". 
I'm just really trying to understand this, I'm not looking for anyone to post code for me. 
Any help or suggestions are appreciated. I've searched Google, on here, youtube, but havent been able to find any help. Yes, I realize this sucks so please dont be rude Im just trying to learn. Thanks.

```
      1
      2 #include <stdio.h>
      3 #include <string.h>
      4 #include <errno.h>
      5 #include <sys/mman.h>
      6 #include <sys/types.h>
      7 #include <unistd.h>
      8
      9     int mem,memused,i, pgsz, *ip;
     10     unsigned char *cp;
     11     void *region;
     12
     13 void heap_init(int num_pages_for_heap)
     14 {
     15     pgsz = getpagesize();
     16     pgsz*=num_pages_for_heap;
     17      mem=pgsz;
     18     region = mmap(NULL, pgsz, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
     19     if (region == ((void *) -1))
     20     {
     21         perror("mmap");
     22        // return 1;
     23     }
     24
     25 }
     26
     27 void *heap_alloc(int num_bytes_to_allocate)
     28 {
     29  if(num_bytes_to_allocate%16 != 0)
     30   {  num_bytes_to_allocate+=8;}
     31
     32     memused+=num_bytes_to_allocate;
     33 if(mem<memused)
     34 { cp=NULL;
     35   return cp;
     36 }
     37
     38 else{
     39  printf("mem used: %d mem: %d region: %p  %d\n",memused,mem,region,&region);
     40    cp = (unsigned char *)region;
     41    *(cp+num_bytes_to_allocate)='a';
     42
     43     ip = (int *)region;
     44    //printf("ip %p, %d\n",ip, &ip);
     45
     46   // *(ip+num_bytes_to_allocate);  // region+1004
     47   // printf("ip %p, %d\n",ip, &ip);
     48   //  *ip+=(num_bytes_to_allocate);
     49
     50     //printf("ip %p\n",ip);
     51     // cp = (unsigned char *)region;
     52     //*cp+=(num_bytes_to_allocate);
     53     //printf("cp %p, %d\n",cp,&cp);
     54
     55  for (i=999; i < num_bytes_to_allocate; i++)//I dont understand why the prof used 999.
     56     {
     57       *(cp+i);
     58
     59     }
     60     printf("\n");
     61
     62
     63 return cp;
     64 }
     65 }
     66 void heap_free(void *pointer_to_area_to_free)
     67 {
     68  //   return;
     69 }
```

//Output for current code used:

```
  mem used: 2000 mem: 8192 region: 0x7f8a62941000  6296176

  mem used: 4000 mem: 8192 region: 0x7f8a62941000  6296176

  mem used: 6000 mem: 8192 region: 0x7f8a62941000  6296176

  mem used: 7008 mem: 8192 region: 0x7f8a62941000  6296176

  mem used: 8016 mem: 8192 region: 0x7f8a62941000  6296176

  Segmentation fault
```

// This is the driver program he gave us:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <string.h>
  4
  5 void heap_init(int num_pages_for_heap);
  6 void *heap_alloc(int num_bytes_to_allocate);
  7 void heap_free(void *pointer_to_area_to_free);  // not used in this test
  8
  9 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 10 {
 11     char *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4, *p5, *p6;
 12
 13     heap_init(2);
 14
 15     p1 = (char *) heap_alloc(2000);
 16     if ((long int)p1 % 16 != 0)
 17     {
 18         printf("p1 bad %p  pmod16 %d\n",p1,((long int)p1)%16);
 19         exit(-1);
 20     }
 21     memset(p1,'X',2000);
 22
 23     p2 = (char *) heap_alloc(2000);
 24     if ((long int)p2 % 16 != 0)
 25     {
 26         printf("p2 bad %p  pmod16 %d\n",p2,((long int)p2)%16);
 27         exit(-1);
 28     }
 29     memset(p2,'X',2000);
 30
 31     p3 = (char *) heap_alloc(2000);
 32     if ((long int)p3 % 16 != 0)
 33     {
 34         printf("p3 bad %p  pmod16 %d\n",p3,((long int)p3)%16);
 35         exit(-1);
 36     }
 37     memset(p3,'X',2000);
 38
 39     p4 = (char *) heap_alloc(1000);
 40     if ((long int)p4 % 16 != 0)
 41     {
 42         printf("p4 bad %p  pmod16 %d\n",p4,((long int)p4)%16);
 43         exit(-1);
 44     }
 45     memset(p4,'X',1000);
 46
 47     p5 = (char *) heap_alloc(1000);
 48     if ((long int)p5 % 16 != 0)
 49     {
 50         printf("p5 bad %p  pmod16 %d\n",p5,((long int)p5)%16);
 51         exit(-1);
 52     }
 53     memset(p5,'X',1000);
 54
 55
 56     p6 = (char *) heap_alloc(1500);  // try 1500 first
 57     if (p6 != NULL)
 58     {
 59         printf("p6 should have been NULL, but is %p\n",p6);
 60         exit(-1);
 61     }
 62
 63     p6 = (char *) heap_alloc(50);   // then just get 50
 64     if ((long int)p6 % 16 != 0)
 65     {
 66         printf("p6 bad %p  pmod16 %d\n",p6,((long int)p6)%16);
 67         exit(-1);
 68     }
 69     memset(p6,'X',50);
 70
 71     printf("DONE\n");
 72
 73     return 0;
 74 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt at `p6` fails like it's supposed to, but as a side-effect, you still update the global `memused` on line 32, before you bail on line 35.

Thus, the next attempt at `p6` also bails at line 35.  (all line numbers relative to the top source listing.)

If you look at the check for the second attempt at `p6` (line 64 in the bottom listing) `p6` is `NULL` again; `NULL % 16 == 0`, so we do not enter the `if` statement.  This means we fall through to the `memset`, whose destination is a `NULL` pointer. (Hence `SIGSEGV`.)

The check you're doing at line 33 in the top listing should probably be done just after line 31, and should be done without affecting the global state.  I.e., `if (mem < (memused + num_bytes_to_allocate))`.  Then `memused` should only be updated if you decide not to bail out early.

Comment: Thanks!! Got it working after reading what you said and utilizing a struct to keep track of everything properly.